# python download/upload api s3(with authorization)

Tags: python, amazon-s3, download

Need help on how to incorporate authentication header , when download from S3 object store using python. I found a few articles using both pycurl and response modules, but none worked for me. *FYI not able to use `boto' module as the end container  where the script will run has python that does not have the module.*

Here is a shell code which works seamless for upload, but i need to make the call from python as this will be part of a larger code which downloads from s3 object store and  massage the data before use.

================

```
bucket=success
file=sample.csv
contentType="text"
dateValue=`date -R`
s3Key=key
s3Secret=secret


  resource="/${bucket}/${file}"
  stringToSign="PUT\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${resource}"
  signature=`echo -en ${stringToSign} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret} -binary | base64`
   curl -L -X PUT -T "${file}" \
  -H "Host: testurl.com/${bucket}" \
  -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
  -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
  -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}" \
   http://testurl.com/${bucket}/${file}
```

================

Appreciate any insight using python only please.
FYI version I am using is python 2.7.

thank you
RD